# Анимация лопастей вертолета SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь анимировать лопасти вертолета. Единственная идея, которая у меня есть, - это сжимать и расширять лопасти вдоль оси X.
Для этого я анимирую атрибут `scale`, однако результаты не такие, как ожидалось. Я предполагаю, что проблема связана с `transform-origin`?

Я не знаю, как это исправить, было бы здорово, если бы кто-то смог помочь.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <g id="helicopter" transform="translate(-400,-150)">
     <g transform="rotate(10 425.701 270.25)">
       <path d="M452.992 256.303v4.547h-1.416l-2.435 9.914h8.814l-2.133-9.914h-1.312v-4.547zm1.252 27.766l-.695.475v2.377l-5.307.006a.858.858 0 000 1.716h23.242l.387-.1 3.096-1.7v-.006a.8.8 0 10-.795-1.385v-.004l-2.285 1.365-.412.113-4.934-.006v-2.318h-1.566v2.318h-9.854v-2.318z M425.701 270.25h42.348c8.82.017 10.296 13.596 0 14.352h-13.44c-4.794-.054-9.567-3.488-9.7-9.7l-20.315-2.173-1.944 3.617c-.443.672-1.027 1.005-1.8.881l.505-5.053v-2.43l-1.819-8.894c.921-.056 1.446.338 1.794.93z" style="fill:#121212"/>
       <path id="blades" d="M481.292 257.313 H426.21 v3.032 l21.124 -.809 v-1.213 h12.835 v1.213 l21.124 .81z" style="fill:#aaaaaa;stroke-width:1px"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#blades" type="scale" values="1 1;0 1;1 1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" dur="1s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#helicopter" type="translate" values="-400,-150;200,-150" dur="25s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animating an SVG helicopter blade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61899491/7394871) от участника  [@Zainab Hussain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10301756/zainab-hussain).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61899491/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Лопасти вертолета можно вращать с помощью `rotateY(360deg)`

Для этого установите центр вращения, используя правила CSS

```
#blades {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

Полный код:

```css
#blades {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: blades 0.15s  infinite;
}
@keyframes blades {
100% {transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="LG" x2="0%" y2="100%">
   <stop offset="85%" stop-color="skyblue"/> 
     <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen"/>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#LG)" /> 
 <g id="helicopter" transform="translate(0,0)">
     <g transform="rotate(10 425.701 270.25)">
       <path d="M452.992 256.303v4.547h-1.416l-2.435 9.914h8.814l-2.133-9.914h-1.312v-4.547zm1.252 27.766l-.695.475v2.377l-5.307.006a.858.858 0 000 1.716h23.242l.387-.1 3.096-1.7v-.006a.8.8 0 10-.795-1.385v-.004l-2.285 1.365-.412.113-4.934-.006v-2.318h-1.566v2.318h-9.854v-2.318z M425.701 270.25h42.348c8.82.017 10.296 13.596 0 14.352h-13.44c-4.794-.054-9.567-3.488-9.7-9.7l-20.315-2.173-1.944 3.617c-.443.672-1.027 1.005-1.8.881l.505-5.053v-2.43l-1.819-8.894c.921-.056 1.446.338 1.794.93z" style="fill:#121212"/>
       <path id="blades" d="M481.292 257.313 H426.21 v3.032 l21.124 -.809 v-1.213 h12.835 v1.213 l21.124 .81z" style="fill:black;stroke-width:1px"/>
        </g>
    </g>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#helicopter" type="translate" values="-400,0;-300,-100;-250,-100;-220,-100;-200,-50;-100,0;100,100" dur="16s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Animating an SVG helicopter blade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900718/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>